# fs.write only registering after closing server

Tags: node.js, logging, fs

I'm programming a chat server, and I'm trying to make chat logs. I'm using fs.write to write the message to a file called logs.txt.

The problem is that the messages don't show up instantly in the log file like I want them to, they only appear after I shut down the server. How can I fix that?

Here's the code I used:

```
fs.open('./logs.txt', 'a', 0666, function(err, fd) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('file could not be opened');
    }
    fs.write(fd, data, 0, data.length, null, function(err, written, buffer) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('log could not be written');
        }
        fs.close(fd, function() { console.log('log written') });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sync version `fs.write` -> `fs.writeSync()`
Actually, saving log like string, I think append message to file is more look ok for me, you can look `fs.appendFileSync` [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_filename_data_options).

Comment: FWIW, the `*Sync()` functions may become a performance bottleneck if you use them a lot, as they block the rest of the program.

Comment: Yep, you can use `fs.appendFile` instance of `fs.appendFileSync` if you don't want block code. Append don't need to close that file at the end.

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons, modern operating systems buffer disk writes in memory and flush to disk once in a while, preferring to make a few writes of many bytes instead of many writes of a few bytes.

Use [`fs.fsync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_fsync_fd_callback) or its synchronous counterpart, the humorously-named `fs.fsyncSync`, to force the operating system to synchronize the in-memory and on-disk contents.

Comment: If you close a filedescriptor, the data should be readable immediately.

Comment: Why does fs.fsync need a synchronous counterpart if it already syncs itself?

Comment: @StigCoder04 `fs.fsync` takes a callback to run after the file descriptor is sync'd by the operating system (on Unix, using the `fsync` C function, cf., [BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fsync&sektion=2)/[Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync)). `fs.fsyncSync` stalls your Node program until the OS says it's done syncing, so it doesn't take a callback.

Comment: @AhmedFasih, I see now.